# Putting one action before every other

Tags: redux-saga

I am new to Redux Saga so sorry if that's obvious, but can't find any solution to my problem.

In my react app I need to get data from token saved in local storage and if it's correct set userId in redux store prior to any other actions (for example fetching data from server for that user) and set axios header for authentication. 
Using yield all([]) obviously doesn't do the trick, and any other ways I tried seem to be really cumbersome for so simple problem.

Comment: can you post some bit of code?

Comment: How do you add this token to local storage ? Can you save it into the redux store instead (which will still probably end up in local storage anyway) so you can use [select](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/)